# Convert a large int to a float between 0.0f and 1.0f

Tags: math, unity-game-engine, numbers

I'm working on a project where I have a pane that goes from 0 to 500 on the x and z, but I need to convert that coordinate (from 0 to 500) to a float in the range of 0.0 to 1.0 in because it is required from some of the functions I'm using.

I'm stuck on how to take the axis position (lets say something like, 3475x3475) and change in into it's relative position on the plane from `0.0f` to `1.0f`

(I've tried to write this in a way that any programmer can understand, instead of using Unity terminology. If you're a Unity programmer and would better understand it with that terminology tell me and I'll re-write it)

Comment: If you are trying to convert a value, x, in the range from 0 to 500 to a floating point between 0 and 1, you can divide x by 500 (i.e. x / 500)

Comment: Assume the relationship in your translation is linear.  For the x-axis, if x1 is the integer value, why can't you solve for x2?: (x1 / 500) = (x2 / 1.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take your number that ranges from 0 to 500 and simply divide it by 500, e.g. `scaled_x = x / 500.0f`.  Depending on the language and the type of `x` you will need to divide by either `500` or `500.0f`.  If you are using a language that has integer division like C, and if `x` is an integer than `x / 500` will be zero unless `x` is 500, but if you do `x/500.0f` than you will get a float between `0.0f` and `1.0f` (assuming x is between 0 and 500 inclusively).  This is of course assuming you want a linear mapping, e.g. 0 maps to 0, 100 maps to 0.2, 250 maps to 0.5 and so on.